# Why does declaring an instance pointer with new keyword inside a function causes problems and undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am learning C++ and came across something interesting while solving challenges on the platform HackerRank. The code is from the Linked List problem. The goal is to display the linked list with the `display` method in the `Solution` class. I noticed that I have to use the new keyword while initializing a class instance for this to work otherwise the code does not detect the end of the list. Please see the following two codes and their respective outputs.

Why is the end of the linked list is not detected correctly when the **new** keyword is not used as in the second code example? I read on the internet that it is discouraged to use **new** as the pointers will need to be explicitly deleted afterwards to avoid a memory leak, so I am pretty confused.

Both codes use the same following input:

**Input**

```
4
2
3
4
1
```

**Code 1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;    
class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int d){
            data=d;
            next=NULL;
        }
};
class Solution{
    public:

      Node* insert(Node *head,int data)
      {
          //Complete this method
        Node* new_node = new Node(data); //Check this line
        if (head) {
          Node *current = head;
          while(current->next) {
            current = current->next;
          }
            current->next = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
          head = new_node;

        }
        //   Node** pp = &head;
        //   while (*pp) {
        //       pp = &((*pp)->next);
        //   }
        //   *pp = new Node(data);
        return head;
   
      }

      void display(Node *head)
      {
          Node *start=head;
          while(start)
          {
              cout<<start->data<<" ";
              start=start->next;
          }
      }
};
int main()
{
    Node* head=NULL;
    Solution mylist;
    int T,data;
    cin>>T;
    while(T-->0){
        cin>>data;
        head=mylist.insert(head,data);
    }   
    mylist.display(head);
        
}
```

**Output 1 (correct)**

```
2 3 4 1
```

**Code 2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;    
class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int d){
            data=d;
            next=NULL;
        }
};
class Solution{
    public:

      Node* insert(Node *head,int data)
      {
          //Complete this method
        Node new_node(data);
        if (head) {
          Node *current = head;
          while(current->next) {
            current = current->next;
          }
            current->next = &new_node;
        }
        else
        {
          head = &new_node;

        }
        //   Node** pp = &head;
        //   while (*pp) {
        //       pp = &((*pp)->next);
        //   }
        //   *pp = new Node(data);
        return head;
   
      }

      void display(Node *head)
      {
          Node *start=head;
          while(start)
          {
              cout<<start->data<<" ";
              start=start->next;
          }
      }
};
int main()
{
    Node* head=NULL;
    Solution mylist;
    int T,data;
    cin>>T;
    while(T-->0){
        cin>>data;
        head=mylist.insert(head,data);
    }   
    mylist.display(head);
        
}
```

**Output 2 (incorrect)**

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1....
```

Comment: Note: Code competition sites like Hackerrank are not particularly good places to learn the basics of C++. They're intended to be used by people already familiar with the language for fun, bragging rights, and maybe a wee bit of practice. The code you find there was written to win, not to to be read and understood by beginners or to demonstrate good technique. For learning C++ it's still hard to beat [a good set of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's true that using `new` requires explicit deallocation, this also means that if you are not using `new`, then somehow the lifetime of the object is already managed implicitly.

This is what happens in your second scenario:

```
Node new_node(data);
head = &new_node;
```

Here you are actually taking the address of a local variable and assign it to a global variable. But the local variable itself ceases to exist whenthe function returns and the address you stored is no longer valid.

When you use `new`, instead, the memory for the object is allocated in a standalone heap and persists as long as you don't `delete` it.

PS. In c++ you can (and should) use `nullptr` instead that `NULL`

Comment: Rules of thumb: don't `delete` something you didn't `new`. And don't return pointers to local variables.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. May I also ask why the pointer to pointer style coding (commented out in the original code) works without modifications?

`Node** pp = &head;
while (*pp) {
  pp = &((*pp)->next);
}
*pp = new Node(data);`

Comment: Anything that leads to undefined behavior simply can't assumed to be working just because in a particular instance it *looks* like it's working. Undefined behavior requires the developer to know that something is not meant to be done because there's no a way to guarantee anything otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained, your data structure was pointing to a local object that had already gone out of scope when the function returned. Accessing a non-existent object results in undefined behavior.

It appears you were attempting to avoid using `new`. One way to avoid explicitly using `new` would be to use a smart pointer to represent your `Node`.

A solution based on `unique_ptr` could look something like:

```
struct Node;
using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;
```

So instead of calling `new`, you would use `make_unique` instead.

```
class Node {
    friend class Solution;

    int data_;
    NodePtr next_;

    static NodePtr make (int d) {
        return std::make_unique<Node>(d);
    }

public:
    Node (int d) : data_(d) {}

};
```

To avoid searching for the last element, you can just maintain a reference to the last element all the time in your list. I implemented a shim called `NodeRef` around `std::reference_wrapper` that makes it act more like a pointer.

```
class Solution {
    NodePtr head_;
    NodeRef tail_;

public:
    Solution () : tail_(head_) {}

    void insert (int d) {
        *tail_ = Node::make(d);
        tail_ = tail_->next_;        
    }

    void display () {
        NodeRef p = head_;
        while (p) {
            std::cout << p->data_ << ' ';
            p = p->next_;
        }
    }
};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNtjtsgFPzPKd6qUtfO1ittu1IlO/ERoqo9QMQCSVAxUMDdRqtcvSkfgWCpVfljizfzZt4AROvuQMjlHZdEzJTBemKTMqcR3Xb2sySOK4lFvcuVdYbhaUTI/8zEwVZRNqDZcnmI/1@cgQ1YR/t@lvzHzHbamXWojMOC9JXt4Q2BXxFs2J4ZJgnbvRqsNUsc320EX9p5boBmYpOl3usW@ohocptGty28nQs@wkD5ltgpA90Ija97jpuNjNTHA3NNO8A/Oav/UArwRSmxwN7dLdGLKSqFzXKkFExYgZ4DTcMNVS1qrNyR27R7RucBXYjA1kaVa6O94UxSSPvflJjDyV4j5dIBxQ7vhsX0kv1yOXXrsOOklCb8nUETeUun0U10GiC7dP7p7BvaZodIzy@Ck77IlV59MtLQeH5hFLS0fFXLRo4M08p2iNRhLoLtWqOwmyAREU2kJpkA@ak49UlYZtxfJltFjj@FoJKGK/OElcvx240pulzMUxcZyq0W@BSvSWmR/WvfphorrNcjFz6jxa0oz4ao2cF6DbobY3bh/x7uhwUyNNXZV6mcqxsTRp4wlzdTJbTpJLh1Q7kr2w9Ah9u7JZ40jrBNW1ev266r3dZAejOQOj@m2KsLUtWuWfm3g87o8ow@ok/oGT2h32Qv8MFeOt96Qx4enj7/AQ)